# Windows 10 Ethernet adapter disappeared

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, ethernet, firewall

My Windows10 PC has no ethernet network connection since yesterday. The port is part of the ASUS X570 motherboard. In '**View Hardware and Connection Properties**':

- **Ethernet**: Status is **Not Present**, Connectivity is **Disconnected**.
- **vEthernet** Status is **Operational** and Connectivity is **Disconnected**.

Ethernet adapter isn't present in Device Manager.

Steps:

- Reset router/modem
- Tried different ethernet ports on the router
- Changed the ethernet cable
- Network Troubleshooter comes up with no results.
- Tried reinitializing all network states as [suggested below](https://superuser.com/a/1680202/1061956).
- Windows Network Reset
- LAN Controller in BIOS is **on**
- Delete vEthernet Adapter in Device Manager
- Green ethernet port LED is **on** when cable is plugged in, orange LED is **flashing**
- Reinstall drivers

The same router is connecting successfully to an RPi4 via ethernet, and wifi works for my MacOS laptop and Android phone.

I'm wondering if this is a firewall or network setup issue. If so, what are steps I could take to troubleshoot? I had previously messed around quite a bit with my ports and firewall settings.

Comment: Can you visually check on your router if there is an active connection ? Does the ethernet adapter show up under Device Manager ? If so, try deleting it and reboot so it will reinstall the driver.

Comment: No Ethernet Adapter listed, but there was a Virtual Ethernet Adapter. I deleted that, but there's been no effect. Can the PC reinstall w/o the internet?

Comment: I added the info of Ethernet adapter missing from Device Manager and edited the title to reflect the actual problem - please verify the info is correct. If this is a desktop PC with a separate LAN card, power it down and re-seat the card. In any case try rebooting as @Silbee suggested - maybe Win finds the adapter. Download a live Linux distro with your RasPi and [dd it to an USB stick](https://linuxiac.com/how-to-create-bootable-usb-drive-using-dd-command/). Boot the PC with that - does it get connection? Please don't answer in a comment, update your question instead.

Comment: Also make use almost all ethernet adapters have a way to visually show they are working and actively moving traffic. Check the lights on your ethernet adapter where you plug in the cable, one should be always on when your PC is on. No lights means the adapter might be dead. You can reinstall windows pro without internet, but home might be a hassle. If the adapter is dead, just buy a pci express lan card or a usb to ethernet adapter. They are cheap and will save you the headache of reinstalling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## It's a HARDWARE PROBLEM

All of the above steps, including @DavidPostill's, are good to take for diagnostics before checking your warranty and shipping the motherboard off for repair (might end up being cheaper to buy a new one).

Comment: how are you sure of this?

Comment: Photograph of the port confirmed damage to the pins that would cost more to repair then to replace.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated (run as Adminstrator) `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults (reboot required):

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still not able to even see the ethernet network :-/

Comment: This is a good idea, but it missing 1 major step. It doesn't do anything if the driver for the network card isn't there.

Comment: @Tonny, how should I access the network card driver? No internet on the PC but I have access to other devices w/o Win10.